# How do I move boolean logic out of my View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC View I pick a sprite based on a boolean value set in the model like this:

```
<div class="sprite-icon_dog<% =(Model.HasNewDog ? "_new" : "") %>"></div>
```

This is ugly and I don't like it.

My objective is to use the `sprite-icon_dog_new` if `Model.HasNewDog` is `true` and use `sprite-icon_dog` if `Model.HasNewDog` is false.

What is a more elegant and more readable way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a HTML Helper would be the way to go?

```
public static string DogDiv(this HTMLHelper html, bool HasDog)
{
  return "...."
}
```

In your view:

```
<%=Html.DogDiv(Model.HasDog) %>
```

Hope that helps,

Dan

Comment: I like your answer and will probably mark it as the correct answer soon. To my own detriment I simplified the question too much. There are more classes in the div than I stated so out the box your answer won't work but it's a great idea and starting point that I may be able to expand on - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but it may be the best option.  If you move the logic to an html helper you are now blurring the lines between what is display and what is business logic.  If you want to change your markup or css, you will be limited to what you can do unless you change code in the Html helper class.

In my opinion, part of that uglyness is getting used to the MVC model.  One of the pillars of MVC is to provide a strict seperation between the display, business logic and data model, but if you start adding display logic in a helper it starts to negate what MVC is intended to do.